# dfs.FSnameSystem.BlockCapacity getting reduced eventually

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

I have a small application that I am running on a 'EMR' Cluster with 3 nodes. I have a few gigabytes of csv files that are split across multiple files. The application reads the csv files and then converts into '.orc' files. I have a small program that sequentially and synchronously sends limited (less than ten) files as input to the application.

My problem is, after sometime, the cluster is going down eventually without leaving any trace (or may be I am looking at wrong places). After trying to find out various options, I observed in 'ganglia' that the dfs.FSNameSystem.BlockCapacity is reducing eventually.

Is this because of the application or is it with the server configuration? Can someone please share if you have any exposure on this?